# Loading tf Keras trained model produces an error

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to load a keras model that was trained before, but I'm getting an error that I don't know what it means.

Could you please help me.

```
2022-08-02 15:54:42.335779: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/m-halwani/tactile_sense/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib
2022-08-02 15:54:42.335832: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/m-halwani/tactile_sense/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib
2022-08-02 15:54:42.335837: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
[[-0.99989037  0.01475083 -0.00128967]
 [ 0.01474901  0.99989023  0.00140958]
 [ 0.00131032  0.0013904  -0.99999817]]
2.1.0
2022-08-02 15:54:42.762094: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-08-02 15:54:42.846489: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2022-08-02 15:54:42.846519: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (mhalwani): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2022-08-02 15:54:42.846842: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2022-08-02 15:54:42.868440: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2304000000 Hz
2022-08-02 15:54:42.869656: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x56038acba3a0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2022-08-02 15:54:42.869669: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "real_time_correction.py", line 354, in <module>
    robot = TactileSensor()
  File "real_time_correction.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.contact_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(contact_model_directory)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 150, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 89, in load
    model = tf_load.load_internal(path, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 552, in load_internal
    export_dir)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 118, in __init__
    super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._load_all()
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 239, in _load_all
    node, setter = self._recreate(proto)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 322, in _recreate
    return factory[kind]()
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 309, in <lambda>
    "user_object": lambda: self._recreate_user_object(proto.user_object),
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 328, in _recreate_user_object
    return self._recreate_base_user_object(proto)
  File "/home/m-halwani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 211, in _recreate_base_user_object
    metadata = json.loads(proto.metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

tensorflow version is 2.1.0

I tried on another llaptop that is using 2.1.0 also and it worked !

Comment: seems you are loading the wrong file, can you show the code you are using and the folder tree?

Comment: As I can see with the error log, you have installed python 2.7, but tensorflow 2.1 is required python version 3.5 - 3.7 as per this [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu). Please try again by updating the [python](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package_location) version between 3.5 to 3.7. Thank you.